# How to manage Custom Video player Zoom In / Zoom Out programmatically?

Tags: android, video, android-video-player

We can achieve CUSTOM video player through two way:

1. VideoView
2. SurfaceView and use MediaPlayer for doing this.

I read a tutorial relate to `Custom Video Player` in which SurfaceView and use MediaPlayer  used for achieving this functionallty - - **[link here](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller)**

What is my need:

How to make your custom view like `"When you touch on the video screen such as zoom out/zoom in, video view goes to the full screen and after zoom in gesture back to fix size what earlier "` ?

Could someone suggest me how to do this thing?

Answer (score 1):

I have share my code with you all i am useing Texture view for zoom in/out using two finger (pinch Zoom)

```
        package com.app.sampletextureview;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
    import android.media.MediaActionSound;
    import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

    import android.util.FloatMath;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
    import android.view.Surface;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.TextureView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import java.io.IOException;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener,View.OnTouchListener {
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        private static final String FILE_NAME = "Vid.mp4";

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        private TextureView mTextureView;
        private RelativeLayout mrRelativeLayout;

        private float mVideoWidth;
        private float mVideoHeight;

        DisplayMetrics dm;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

        private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
        private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

        // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image

        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

        // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
        PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;

        private float mVideoWidth;
    private float mVideoHeight;



    int viewWidth=0,viewHeight=0,xoff=0,yoff=0;;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            calculateVideoSize();

            initView();

        }
        private void initView() {

            mrRelativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
            mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);

            mTextureView.setOnTouchListener(this);


            /*Log.d("Height-WidthOnCreate",""+mVideoHeight+"-"+mVideoWidth);
            mTextureView.setMinimumWidth((int)mVideoWidth);

            mTextureView.setMinimumHeight((int)mVideoHeight);

            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);


        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
            Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);

                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

                // don't forget to call MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() method when you use constructor for
                // creating MediaPlayer
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                adjustAspectRatio((int) mVideoWidth, (int)mVideoHeight);
                    Log.d("SurfaceCreate",""+mVideoWidth+""+mVideoHeight);



                // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }




        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {



            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }

        private void calculateVideoSize() {
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
                MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                metaRetriever.setDataSource(
                        afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                String height = metaRetriever
                        .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
                String width = metaRetriever
                        .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
                mVideoHeight = Float.parseFloat(height);
                mVideoWidth = Float.parseFloat(width);

                Log.d("Height-Width",""+mVideoHeight+"-"+mVideoWidth);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }


        private void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
            float scaleX = 1.0f;
            float scaleY = 1.0f;

            if (mVideoWidth > viewWidth && mVideoHeight > viewHeight) {
                scaleX = mVideoWidth / viewWidth;
                scaleY = mVideoHeight / viewHeight;
            } else if (mVideoWidth < viewWidth && mVideoHeight < viewHeight) {
                scaleY = viewWidth / mVideoWidth;
                scaleX = viewHeight / mVideoHeight;
            } else if (viewWidth > mVideoWidth) {
                scaleY = (viewWidth / mVideoWidth) / (viewHeight / mVideoHeight);
            } else if (viewHeight > mVideoHeight) {
                scaleX = (viewHeight / mVideoHeight) / (viewWidth / mVideoWidth);
            }

            // Calculate pivot points, in our case crop from center
            int pivotPointX = viewWidth / 2;
            int pivotPointY = viewHeight / 2;

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);

            mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);

        }


        private void adjustAspectRatio(int videoWidth, int videoHeight) {
            int viewWidth = mTextureView.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = mTextureView.getHeight();
            double aspectRatio = (double) videoHeight / videoWidth;

            int newWidth, newHeight;
            if (viewHeight > (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio)) {
                // limited by narrow width; restrict height
                newWidth = viewWidth;
                newHeight = (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio);
            } else {
                // limited by short height; restrict width
                newWidth = (int) (viewHeight / aspectRatio);
                newHeight = viewHeight;
            }
            int xoff = (viewWidth - newWidth) / 2;
            int yoff = (viewHeight - newHeight) / 2;
            Log.v(TAG, "video=" + videoWidth + "x" + videoHeight +
                    " view=" + viewWidth + "x" + viewHeight +
                    " newView=" + newWidth + "x" + newHeight +
                    " off=" + xoff + "," + yoff);

            Matrix txform = new Matrix();
            mTextureView.getTransform(txform);
            txform.setScale((float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
            //txform.postRotate(10);          // just for fun
            txform.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);
            mTextureView.setTransform(txform);
        }


      /*  @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            return true;
        }
    */



        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
                SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
                matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
                Log.d("Matrix", "" + scaleFactor);
                mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);

                return true;
            }
        }


     @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {



        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...


        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only

                if (!istouch) {
                    istouch=true;
                    ll_bottombar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll_topheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hideSystemUI(getWindow());

                }else{
                    String tag = btnLock.getTag().toString();
                    if (tag.equals("false")) {
                        istouch = false;
                        ll_bottombar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ll_topheader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        hideSystemUI(getWindow());

                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down
           //case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:

                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);

                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                   savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                  //  matrix.setScale( mid.y,(float) newWidth / viewWidth,mid.x, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
                   // matrix.setScale(mid.x,mid.y);
                    if(event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
                        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
                        mode = ZOOM;

                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                    }

                }
               break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == NONE)
            {
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");

            }
                if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
               /* if (mode == DRAG)
                {

                    // matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    //  matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                }else if (mode == NONE)
            {
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");

            }*/
                 if (mode == ZOOM) {

                        // pinch zooming
                        float newDist = spacing(event);

                        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                        if (newDist > 5f) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            Log.d(TAG, "NEW="+newDist+"--"+oldDist);
                            Log.d(TAG, "NEW Mid Point="+mid.x+"--"+mid.y);
                            scale = newDist / oldDist;
                           // matrix.setScale();
                           // matrix.setScale(scale,scale);
                            matrix.postScale(scale,scale,mid.x, mid.y);


                            Log.d(TAG,"New Hight Width"+mTextureView.getWidth()+"--"+mTextureView.getHeight());

                        }

                    }

                    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
                }


                break;
        }

      // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }
      /*  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
         * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
         * ----------------------------------------------------
    */


        private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

       /*  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
         * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
         * ------------------------------------------------------------

        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
        {
            float x = mrRelativeLayout.getX()+mrRelativeLayout.getWidth();
            float y = mrRelativeLayout.getY()+mrRelativeLayout.getHeight();
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }


        private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int action = event.getAction();
            int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

            if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
            {
                sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                sb.append(")");
            }

            sb.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
            {
                sb.append("#").append(i);
                sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                    sb.append(";");
            }

            sb.append("]");
        }



    private void adjustAspectRatio(int videoWidth, int videoHeight) {

     viewWidth = mTextureView.getWidth();
         viewHeight = mTextureView.getHeight();

        double aspectRatio = (double) videoHeight / videoWidth;


        if (viewHeight > (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio)) {
            // limited by narrow width; restrict height
            newWidth = viewWidth;
            newHeight = (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio);
        } else {
            // limited by short height; restrict width
            newWidth = (int) (viewHeight / aspectRatio);
            newHeight = viewHeight;
        }

        xoff = (viewWidth - newWidth) / 2;

        yoff = (viewHeight - newHeight) / 2;


        Log.d(TAG, "video=" + videoWidth + "x" + videoHeight +
                " view=" + viewWidth + "x" + viewHeight +
                " newView=" + newWidth + "x" + newHeight +
                " off=" + xoff + "," + yoff);

        Log.d(TAG, "video="+mTextureView.getHeight()+"--"+mTextureView.getWidth());
        Log.d(TAG, "video="+newHeight+"--"+newWidth);
        mTextureView.setMinimumWidth(newWidth);
        mTextureView.setMinimumHeight(newHeight);

       // Matrix txform = new Matrix();
        mTextureView.getTransform(matrix);
        matrix.setScale((float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
        //txform.postRotate(10);          // just for fun
        matrix.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

}
    }
```

Comment: In above code i have use "Texture View " for play video and and i have put video file in row folder. for  video zoom in/out private **ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();**